# Craft update process affecting Element API cache

Tags: cache, plugin-elementapi, updating

I have a site A using the Element API plugin to feed content to site B via JSON and handlebars templates. The process is both sites are up to date with content 'x' and it works fine.

When I run the CP updates on site A and it finishes the data on site B never shows until the site A cache is cleared.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Not sure I'm following 100%, but the data doesn't show up on the front-end of site B until you clear Craft's caches?  Are you using the template `{% cache %}` tag or some other caching solution?

Answer (score 1):

Got to the bottom of it. It was a CORS thing - permission with the domain htaccess and elementAPI. A shift from non-www, to www redirection seemed to be the cause so now solved